# [GWT]Is it possible to select menuItem onMouseOver?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jakarta-ee, gwt2

I realize a web application that  run commands displayed in menuItem. These commands may depend on each other, for example if a command C depends on B, B depends on A  to execute C we must execute in order A-> B-> C. In short, I would like to improve the feedback on my application and select menuItems automatically when the mouse is over a command that depends on them.
Thanks in advance for your helps.
NB: I use GWT 2.3

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that isn't possible with the methods that gwt provides. `MenuItem` is a direct subclass of `UiObject`, That's the same superclass `Widget` inherits from, but MenuItem is no Widget. The problem is that all the event functions are defined in Widget, not in UiObject.

You could try to create the class `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MenuItem` in your own project, thus "overriding" the gwt class, let it inherit from Widget, copy the original MenuItem into and implement the necessary interfaces. I would NOT recommend that, though. I almost feel ashamed for even mentioning it.
A more elegant solution would be to create a MyMenuItem class in your own package. Copy the content of MenuItem to it, but let it inherit from Widget instead. Then you use a rebinding rule in your .gwt.xml to replace MenuItem with MyMenuItem. Just remember to copy MenuItem again when you change the GWT version.

Alternatively, you could override MenuItem and add your own event handling functions. You could look at `Widget` and its subclasses (TextField, Button...) to see how that would have to be done. A good place to start would be `Widget#addDomHandler`. It's not as complex as it sounds - the dirty work is hidden in the `DOM` class of GWT which is also used by the Widget class. It's mostly copy/paste. The drawback is that your class might not work anymore if you want to use a new GWT version and needs to be rewritten.

Personally, i wouldn't implement such a selection as an instant mouseover-effect. It sounds good for new users, but as an experienced user, i would be annoyed. normally, menu items are grouped on the screen, so when i want a specific menu item, most of times i have to mouseover other items, too. resulting in flashing menu items - annoying, especially when i did that a hundred times already and know the dependencies of the commands. May i recommend combining that with a timer, so that the dependencies are selected after a certain time, 500ms for example? experienced users click fast enough to not be bothered with it, and new users can - if needed - wait a bit to get thus extra help.

Oh, and if you really want to do this - mouseover isn't enough. you have to listen to focus events, too - many users use their keyboard for navigation, which isnt caught by mouseover, but fires focus events.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and here is a solution for this annoying problem.
When you take a look at the `MenuBar` class, you can see that the events are handled for each MenuItem within the MenuBar.
The only thing to do is to override the `public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)` method of the MenuBar, and find wich item received the event:

```
menu = new MenuBar(true) {
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
            MenuItem currentItem = null;
            for (MenuItem item : itemList) {
                if (DOM.isOrHasChild(item.getElement(), DOM.eventGetTarget(event))) {
                    //MenuItem found here
                    currentItem = item;
                }
            }
            switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
            case Event.ONMOUSEOVER:
                if (currentItem != null) {
                    // DO WHAT YOU GOTTA DO HERE
                }
                break;              
            }
            super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        }
    };
```

You can also create a custom MenuItem to bind other information in it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier solution compared to the previous one - just use the `setAutoOpen(true)` method on your `MenuBar` ([Docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html#setAutoOpen%28boolean%29)). Then all the child menus will open when the user moves the mouse over them.